# Reproduce the "--max-depth=" switch for disk-usage command on AIX

Tags: aix, disk-usage

When I work on Linux/GNU distro environment I often use that wonderfull command

```
du --max-depth=1 /
```

That gives you the size of each folder in your `root` directory. Today I work with AIX and sysadmin does not want to heard about GNU.
Is there any tool or command line that allow to reproduce the switch `--max-depth` on AIX for `du` command ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just remove the lines from the sub-directories (that assumes directory names don't have newline characters in them):

```
du | grep -v '/.*/'
```

or:

```
du | awk -F/ 'NF <= 2'
```

Note that it won't be significantly slower than GNU's `du --max-depth=1` as the costly part is `lstat`ing all the files which needs to be done for both.

If you can't guarantee that directory names won't have newline characters in them:

```
du .//. | awk '
  function process() {
    if (p != "" && split(p, a, "/") <= 4) {
      sub("//.", "", p);
      print p
    }
  }
  /\/\// {process(); p=$0; next}
  {p = p "\n" $0}
  END {process()}'
```

Comment: I guess I need to use `/.*/.*/` for `--max-depth=2` ?

Comment: @Kiwy, or use `awk -F/ 'NF <= 3'`

Comment: thank but I'll stick with grep, I'm really uncomfortable with that `awk`ward binary